# On a colon ideal in the polynomial ring $\mathbb R[x,y]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, monomial-ideals

> Consider the ring $R=\mathbb R[x,y]$. Let $\mathfrak m=(x,y)$. Let $n\ge 3$ be an odd integer and let $I_n=(x^n,y^n)$. What is the smallest integer $s\ge 1 $ (obviously depending on $n$) such that $(I_n\mathfrak m^s:\mathfrak m)\subseteq I_n$?

(For ideals $I,J$ in a ring $R$, $(I:J):=\{r\in R \mid rJ \subseteq I\}$; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient.)

NOTE:

$(I_n\mathfrak m^s : \mathfrak m)$

$=(y^{n+s}R +\sum_{j=0}^s x^{n+j-1}y^{s-j}R + \sum_{j=1}^s x^{j-1}y^{n+s-j}R ) \cap (x^{n+s}R +\sum_{j=0}^{s-1} x^{n+j}y^{s-j-1}R+  \sum_{j=0}^s x^{j}y^{n+s-j-1}R) $

Comment: @user113102: I've edited now ... I've tried some things without any progress ... I believe the question is not very easy ...

Comment: Can you write down a set of generators for the colon ideal? Then you should be able to find the s that guarantees it lies in $I_n$.

Comment: @user113102: finding generators for colon ideals is in general difficult. However, for monomial ideals, some progress can be made: $(I_n\mathfrak m^s : \mathfrak m)=( \sum_{j=0}^s (x^{n+j-1}y^{s-j})+ (y^{n+s}) + \sum_{j=1}^s (x^{j-1}y^{n+s-j}) ) \cap (\sum_{j=0}^{s-1} (x^{n+j}y^{s-j-1})+ (x^{n+s}) + \sum_{j=0}^s (x^{j}y^{n+s-j-1})) $

Comment: For $s=n-1$ we have that $x^{n-1}y^{n-1}$ belongs to the colon ideal, but not to $I_n$. Then show that $s=n$ works. And don't forget that these are monomial ideals!

Comment: If my calculations are correct, this question has nothing to do with $n$ *odd*.